# Is it possible that $QR_p = QR_p + x$ for some $p,x$?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-progressions

Let $QR_p \subseteq \mathbb{F}_p^*$ be the set of quadratic residues modulo $p$.

Is there a prime $p$ and an integer $x \not = 0$ mod $p$ such that $QR_p$ is invariant under addition with $x$?

i.e. $QR_p = QR_p + x := \{(q+x)~mod~p~|~q \in QR_p\}$

I think the answer should be no. If the answer was yes, there would be an arithmetic progression with common difference $x$, but I don't know how to prove/disprove the statement.

Comment: Couldn't you always take $x$ to be a multiple of $p$?

Comment: @BenS. the addition $QR_p + x$ is supposed to be carried out mod $p$, i'll edit that in

Comment: @BenS. nvm i missunderstood. if $x$ is a multiple of $p$, then $x$ is considered to be $0$

Comment: @user236182 please elaborate, I don't see why we need $0 \equiv 0 + x$

Comment: @user236182 please write up a more lengthy argument, i still don't follow

Comment: @user236182 i defined it in line 3: the set $QR$ does not change under element-wise addition by $x$

Comment: It's definitely true that for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ there exists $m_n$ such that $nx\equiv m_n^2\pmod{p}$ ...does that help at all?

Answer (score 1):

If $0$ is considered a quadratic residue mod $p$: No such $x$ exists. Note that $0\in QR_p$, so $x+0\equiv q^2\pmod{p}$ implies that $x$ is a quadratic residue. In order for $QR_p+x$ to be equal to $QR_p$, we would need $nx$ to be a quadratic residue mod $p$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$; clearly this is not true, since if take $n$ to be any number which is not a quadratic residue mod $p$, then $nx\notin QR_p$.

If $0$ is not considered a quadratic residue mod $p$: No such $x$ exists. Note that for fixed $m\in QR_p$, we would need $nx-m\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, taking $n=m$ yields: $m(x-1)\equiv0\pmod{p}$, so $p|m$ (not true) or $p|(x-1)$, which would mean that $x$ has to be $1$. Now, let $n$ be a not quadratic residue mod $p$. Then $(n-1)mx+m=nm$ is not a quadratic residue mod $p$.

Comment: $QR_p$ is meant to be a set in $\mathbb{F}_p^*$, hence $0 \not \in QR_p$. I should've clarified that. Nevertheless, your answer works when zero is considered a qr.

Comment: We could also take y to be any quadratic residue mod p, and observe that $\{y+n x : 0\leq n <p\} $  mod p is a complete reside class mod p and so it has p members mod p, but for odd p,the set $ QR_p$  has  (p+1)/2 members.Now for my great moment: IT IS TRUE  WHEN p=2  (!!)